# how to make script file (bat) that make 2 actions

Tags: scripting, installation, cmd

how to make script file (bat) that make 2 actions

1. i need to delete any policies (if there is) in:

   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/policies]
2. i need to run this (in command mode - cmd):

   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -i

is there any way to do it in one script file ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REG.EXE DELETE \\%COMPUTERNAME%\HKLM\SOFTWARE\policies /va /f

CMD.EXE /C C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -i